# SimpleAPI の Wikipedia API が使用できない

Tags: webapi

http://wikipedia.simpleapi.net にアクセスしても、"wikipedia api is too busy" と表示され、使用できなくなりました。原因をご存じですか。以前は動作していました。

Comment: 原因は存じ上げない(※別コメントで後述)のですが、[SimpleAPI](http://www.simpleapi.net/)は[株式会社ユーザーローカル](https://www.userlocal.jp/)様が運営しておられますので、[問い合わせフォーム](https://inquiry.userlocal.jp/form/)から直接お問い合わせされた方が手っ取り早いかもしれません。

Comment: ※公式サイトにsimpleapiのアナウンスが載っておらず、公式Facebook、Twitterの更新もしばらくされていませんでした。Google検索で[直近1ヶ月の情報を検索](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wikipedia.simpleapi.net%22&tbs=qdr:m)してもヒットしないので、予期せぬ内部エラーが発生している可能性があります。その場合は外部からの原因究明と対策は不可能かもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

マニュアルも削除されていますので公開を停止したのではと思います。
代用としてこちらのサービスが使用できそうです。

https://excelapi.org/docs/language/#Wikipedia%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%AE%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97